How to fix AppComponent is standalone, and cannot be declared in an NgModule?
Sharing my app.module code:
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { GifComponent } from '../gif/gif.component';
import { GifDetailComponent } from '../gif/gif-detail.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { app } from '../../server';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GifComponent,
    GifDetailComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] // Bootstrap AppComponent
})
export class AppModule { }

app.component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: true, // Add this line
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'compiled';
  gifs = [
    { title: 'GIF1', src: 'assets/gif1.gif' },
    { title: 'GIF2', src: 'assets/gif2.gif' },
    // Gifs
  ];

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  redirectToGif(gif: { title: string, src: string }) {
    this.router.navigate(['/gif', gif.title]);
  }
}

main.ts:
import { enableProdMode, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component'; // Import AppComponent
import { environment } from './environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(moduleRef => {
    const applicationRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
    const componentRef = applicationRef.bootstrap(AppComponent); // Bootstrap AppComponent
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

If I delete the standalone component, I'm getting this error message:

The AppComponent component is not marked as standalone

Any options what should I do?
I tried to remove the standalone component but I'm getting another error message.
Here is a GitHub link: https://github.com/BekaEn/GifApp

Your project is configured to start the Angular application with a standalone component (in server.ts). Hence, you don't need to bootstrap the application with AppModule (bootstrapModule) in main.ts.
main.ts: Remove whole platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule) line
As you bootstrap the application with the standalone component, you can import AppModule (to import non-standalone component(s)) in the appConfig as below:
app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GifComponent,
    GifDetailComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule, // Add RouterModule to imports array
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }

app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration(),
  importProvidersFrom(AppModule)]
};

Besides, you should import these standalone components in AppComponent too.
app.component.ts
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterLink, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: true, // Add this line
  imports: [RouterLink, RouterOutlet, NgFor]
})
export class AppComponent { ... }


You may refer to Demo and commit.

According to Angular official docs starting ver 19, in order to keep your components modular, you simply need to update your components to standalone: false
